# Retrieve the second latest record with same id

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following four records, I want to select the `OwnerId` of second-latest record

```
ItemId  OwnerId Date
11477   20981   2013-05-13
11477   1       2013-05-21
11477   21086   2013-05-22 #this is the one I'm talking about
11477   3868    2013-05-24
```

How to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs `ItemID` to be specified,

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  ItemID = '11477'
ORDER  BY DATE DESC
LIMIT  1,1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/898adb/1)

However, if you don't want to specify the `ItemID`, and you want to get all second latest record for every `ItemID`, you can use a correlated subquery to generate a sequence number for every `ItemID` based on lastest `DATE`,

```
SELECT  ItemId, OwnerID, Date
FROM
        (
            SELECT  A.ItemId, 
                    A.OwnerId, 
                    A.Date,
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    tableName c
                        WHERE   c.ItemId = a.ItemId AND
                                c.Date >= a.Date) AS RowNumber
            FROM    TableName a
        ) x
WHERE   RowNumber = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/188cb/1)

Comment: Accepted for I was looking for the second query, +1 for fiddles.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ownerid
from your_table
order by date desc
limit 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just to `ORDER BY` date descending, which will give you an order from newer to older, then  `LIMIT 1,1` to get only the second result, which should be the one you look for

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```